# PHP imagejpeg doesn't work

Tags: php

So I looked almost every question and tried to work to show my image using the php script below. But it doesn't work. I also tried to see if GD library is enabled with PHPInfo() and it is working as well. I am very new to PHP but can't seem to get this working. Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I get a broken image icon after I click on upload a doc button.

```
<?php
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
if(isset($_FILES['photo'])
        && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])
        && $_FILES['photo']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            foreach ($_FILES['photo'] as $key => $value) {
                echo "$key : $value<br />";
            }
            if($_FILES['photo']['type'] == 'image/jpeg') {
                $tmp_img = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_img);
                header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
                imagejpeg($image,NULL);
                imagedestroy($image);
            } else {
                echo "Uploaded file ewas not a jpg image.";
            }
                echo "no photo uploaded.";
              }
}
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="book.php" method="post">
<input type="file" name="photo">
<input type="submit" value="upload a doc">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try add `die();` after `imagedestroy($image);` to prevent any other output except image data. Also change `imagejpeg($image,NULL);` to `imagejpeg($image);`.

Comment: remove this also `foreach ($_FILES['photo'] as $key => $value) {
                echo "$key : $value<br />";
            }`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access to image direcly with `tmp_name`. Firstly you should save the image to the server and after that you can use with `imagecreatefromjpeg`

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
if(isset($_FILES['photo'])
        && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])
        && $_FILES['photo']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            if($_FILES['photo']['type'] == 'image/jpeg') {
                $tmp_img = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
                $uniq_name = uniqid().".".explode(".",$tmp_img)[1];
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'],$uniq_name);
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($uniq_name);
                header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
                imagejpeg($image);
                imagedestroy($image);
            } else {
                echo "Uploaded file ewas not a jpg image.";
            }
                echo "no photo uploaded.";
              }
}
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="book.php" method="post">
<input type="file" name="photo">
<input type="submit" value="upload a doc">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies with the `echo` and the output strings after the PHP section (HTML code). Remove the `foreach` loop and output HTML only if it is a new page or if something is wrong.

```
<?php
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(isset($_FILES['photo'])
        && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])
        && $_FILES['photo']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            if($_FILES['photo']['type'] == 'image/jpeg') {
                $tmp_img = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_img);
                header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
                imagejpeg($image,NULL);
                imagedestroy($image);
                exit; // Add this to stop the program here.
            } else {
                echo "Uploaded file was not a jpg image.";
            }
    } else {
      echo 'No file was sent.';
    }
}
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="book.php" method="post">
<input type="file" name="photo">
<input type="submit" value="upload a doc">
</form>
```

And one other thing, if you code using Notepad, be sure that there are no hidden characters at the beginning of your file.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I did what you wrote. Also, I removed white space between the start of the code and the top of the file. How can the white space create an error? Is it the "hidden characters"? Also, I am using Sublime Text. Thank you!

Comment: There two points: first is that outputting any character will cause a warning because of `header` function and this warning may destroy the image. and the second point is that any extra character which is sent to the browser will be assumed as a part of picture. even spaces.